# Problema al subir archivo a bbdd con sql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

No consigo que me funcione este código para subir el archivo a la bbdd.

Si que se guarda en el directorio pero no a la bbdd.

Código:

```
<?php

        $nombre_archivo = $_FILES['archivo'] ['name'];
        $tipo_archivo = $_FILES['archivo'] ['type'];
        $tamano_archivo = $_FILES['archivo'] ['size'];

        if($tamano_archivo < 2048000){

                //Ruta carpeta imagenes
                $carpeta_destino = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/intranet/uploads/';
                //Mover imagen del temporal al definitivo
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES['archivo'] ['tmp_name'],$carpeta_destino.$nombre_archivo);

        } else {

            echo 'Has excedido el tamaño de la imagen';
        }

        require('connect.php');

        $connection=mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);

        if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
            echo "Error de conexión";
            exit();
        }

        mysqli_select_db($connection, $db_name) or die ("No se encuentra la BBDD");
        mysqli_set_charset($connection, "utf8");

        $archivo_objetivo=fopen($carpeta_destino.$nombre_archivo, "r");
        $contenido=fread($archivo_objetivo, $tamano_archivo);
        $contenido=addslashes($contenido);
        fclose($archivo_objetivo);

        $query="INSERT INTO files (id, nombre, tipo, arv) VALUES ('', '$nombre_archivo', '$tipo_archivo', '$contenido')";
        $result=mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if(mysqli_affected_rows($connection)>0) {
            echo 'Se ha insertado el archivo con exito';
        } else {
            echo 'El archivo no se ha insertado';
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: Hola Xavi, en la linea del INSERT, el ID lo pones como vació...esto no tiene mucha lógica. postea la estructura de la BB.DD para saber mas

Answer (score 0):

Hace falta algo más de información. Lo primero que te recomiendo es no guardar un fichero en la base de datos, no están pensadas para ello aunque lo permitan, en su lugar guarda una URI.

Por otro lado, si insistes, el campo destino debe ser del tipo BLOB. Comparte la estructura de la base de datos para ayudarte.

Un saludo.

Comment: Hola Jess, esto no es una respuesta si no un comentario. Ya se que no tienes reputacion para comentar en cualquier parte e intentas ayudar pero es un privilegio que has de ganar. Las respuestas tienen que seguir la guia [answer]. Ahora no puedes eliminarla al tener un voto positivo. Un saludo y animo hasta los 50 rep

Comment: Muchas gracias, me leeré la guia antes de seguir interactuando por acá :) un saludo.